# Too much CPU consumption by boost scoped_lock

Tags: c++, macos, boost, mutex, boost-interprocess

I have some code which waits for write operation on Shared Memory.
If no one writes it continues to wait.

```
    Test* Foo::Get() 
    {
        boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex> lock ( mutex ) ; // mutex is boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex
        if ( this->check == 0 )
            this->interprocessCondition.wait ( lock ) ; // interprocessCondition is boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition

...
    }
```

When i did sampling, I found out it consumes around 90% of CPU.

Can some one help me fix this performance problem? Please see the attached image.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Are you doing anything else or are you just profiling the lock?  What does the 'something else' code look like?

Comment: Its just reading from Shared Memory in somethingelse. I profiled complete executable.

Comment: That doesn't help much.  It is normal for taking a lock to take a *lot* more cpu than reading an int from shared memory.  You solve it by making the lock less fine-grained.

Comment: More debugging points to `inline void sched_yield()`, for windows it calls Sleep(1) but I cannot find any definition for Mac?

Comment: What does 90% CPU mean? Does it create a busy-loop for a period of time, or does it actually yield to another process?

Comment: I have added image. I guess it  calls sched_yield(); but there is no defination of sched_yield(); for UNIX systems, thus it continously repeats execution in loop.

Comment: As a side note, waiting on a condition may return due to a [spurious wakeup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup). Hence, it is better to use `while` instead of `if` for state checking: while(this->check == 0) this->interprocessCondition.wait(lock);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost::interprocess`, unfortunately, uses busy-waiting for locks on many platforms (apparently including OSX). You'll want to use a lock native to your platform that actually sleeps.

Comment: Or fortunately, it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I added sleep(1) in place of sched_yield(); call? Now its very pretty nice. Will it have any side effects, apart from I have to look out for boost update not disturbing code?

Comment: @MacGeek, this will greatly increase wakeup latency

Comment: But, Boost uses sleep(1) for Windows? Shouldn't the effect has to be same?

Comment: @MacGeek, on OS X, `sleep(1)` waits one second. On Windows, `Sleep(1)` waits one _millisecond_.

Comment: Ah! Then I guess usleep(1000) should be fine?

Comment: @MacGeek, it probably won't be very much different from yielding :/

Comment: I cannot rework on this part as it's also present on windows. For now I will use usleep() and then, later in future I can re-factor it marking todo. I am Skeptic too about this but don't have enough time. Thank you bdonlan.